# Is there a way to use a .cshtml file as the popup in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, razor, google-chrome-extension

I want to be able to use the view functionality that a .cshtml would provide me. Is there anyway to make this happen? I already have one loaded but it outputs as plain text. 
Is there some service or project that will render a .cshtml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using Partial View. Here below sample code for this.

```
<div class="row">
    <label>Id : </label>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)

    <label>Name: </label>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
```

then create one action in your controller like

```
public PartialViewResult GetProfilePartial()
{
     var model = new ProfileViewModel()
     {
          Id = 1,
          Name = "Sample User";
     };
     return PartialView("PartialViewName", model);
 }
```

You can import rendered html of this view by calling GetProfilePartial action by ajax call. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Again; that requires hosting a page on a server that's separate from the extension.

Answer (score 1):

No.

`cshtml` requires a specific server to render it properly, and that is not part of Chrome.

I mean, technically you can host a page somewhere and embed it in the popup as an `<iframe>`, but I doubt that's an acceptable solution.